# Remove trailing spaces from a file using Windows batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How could I trim all trailing spaces from a text file using the Windows command prompt?

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I would like to this from the command line. Possibly w/o any additional software

Comment: I forgot to mention. I would like to do this by using machine language. Preferably without using an assembler or compiler :-) _Use_ the tools you can, that's what they're for. Otherwise you're wasting time re-inventing wheels (and probably making them square as well).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DosTips RTRIM function that Ben Hocking cites can be used to create a script that can right trim each line in a text file. However, the function is relatively slow.

DosTips user (and moderator) aGerman developed a [very efficient right trim algorithm](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=12286). He implemented the algorithm as a batch "macro" - an interesting concept of storing complex mini scripts in environment variables that can be executed from memory. The macros with arguments are a major discussion topic in and of themselves that is not relevent to this question.

I have extracted aGerman's algorithm and put it in the following batch script. The script expects the name of a text file as the only parameter and proceeds to right trim the spaces off each line in the file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "spcs= "
for /l %%n in (1 1 12) do set "spcs=!spcs!!spcs!"
findstr /n "^" "%~1" >"%~1.tmp"
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
(
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%~1.tmp") do (
    set "ln=%%L"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "ln=!ln:*:=!"
    set /a "n=4096"
    for /l %%i in (1 1 13) do (
      if defined ln for %%n in (!n!) do (
        if "!ln:~-%%n!"=="!spcs:~-%%n!" set "ln=!ln:~0,-%%n!"
        set /a "n/=2"
      )
    )
    echo(!ln!
    endlocal
  )
) >"%~1"
del "%~1.tmp" 2>nul
```

Assuming the script is called rtrimFile.bat, then it can be called from the command line as follows:

```
rtrimFile "fileName.txt"
```

**A note about performance**
The original DosTips rtrim function performs a linear search and defaults to trimming a maximum of 32 spaces. It has to iterate once per space.

aGerman's algorithm uses a binary search and it is able to trim the maximum string size allowed by batch (up to ~8k spaces) in 13 iterations.

Unfotunately, batch is very SLOW when it comes to processing text. Even with the efficient rtrim function, it takes ~70 seconds to trim a 1MB file on my machine. The problem is, just reading and writing the file without any modification takes significant time. This answer uses a FOR loop to read the file, coupled with FINDSTR to prefix each line with the line number so that blank lines are preserved. It toggles delayed expansion to prevent `!` from being corrupted, and uses a search and replace operation to remove the line number prefix from each line. All that before it even begins to do the rtrim.

Performance could be nearly doubled by using an [alternate file read mechanism that uses `set /p`](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2128). However, the set /p method is limited to ~1k bytes per line, and it strips trailing control characters from each line.

If you need to regularly trim large files, then even a doubling of performance is probably not adequate. Time to download (if possible) any one of many utilities that could process the file in the blink of an eye.

If you can't use non-native software, then you can try VBScript or JScript excecuted via the CSCRIPT batch command. Either one would be MUCH faster.

**UPDATE - Fast solution with JREPL.BAT**

[JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) is a regular expression find/replace utility that can very efficiently solve the problem. It is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. No 3rd party exe files are needed.

With JREPL.BAT somewhere within your PATH, you can strip trailing spaces from file "test.txt" with this simple command:

```
jrepl " +$" "" /f test.txt /o -
```

If you put the command within a batch script, then you must precede the command with CALL:

```
call jrepl " +$" "" /f test.txt /o -
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this, as soon as Im up to it again.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I wish I could understand this script in detail, w/o having to become a batch expert :)

Comment: PS Just a small feedback on performance, it is trimming a big text file with a rate of little less than 1 MB / sec on a dual intel 2.66 GHz, xp sp3, 2GB RAM. I know the above means almost nothing, but just fyi. For me, if Im to trim a 10MB file, it would mean more than 10 mins ... So, the question is: Could you imagine some limits for the above batch, and some possibility to increase performance? The line set /a "k=4096"%\n% sets some buffer or what is it good for?

Comment: @HeinrichStack Oops, the set /a k... line was an accidental holdover from aGerman's original code. It was harmless, but not needed - I've eliminated it. I think you have typo/math error - I wish this was as fast as 1MB/sec ;) I get a bit less than 1MB/min. I'll add an addendum about performance.

Answer (score 5):

Go get yourself a copy of [CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [the `sed` package](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html).

Then use that with the command:

```
sed "s/ *$//" inputFile >outputFile
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention, that I want to trim the trailing whitespaces without any additional software. Just with the preinstalled files on the OS.

Answer (score 2):

Dos Tips has an [implementation of RTrim](http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#Function.rTrim) that works for batch files:

```
:rTrim string char max -- strips white spaces (or other characters) from the end of a string
::                     -- string [in,out] - string variable to be trimmed
::                     -- char   [in,opt] - character to be trimmed, default is space
::                     -- max    [in,opt] - maximum number of characters to be trimmed from the end, default is 32
:$created 20060101 :$changed 20080219 :$categories StringManipulation
:$source http://www.dostips.com
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
call set string=%%%~1%%
set char=%~2
set max=%~3
if "%char%"=="" set char= &rem one space
if "%max%"=="" set max=32
for /l %%a in (1,1,%max%) do if "!string:~-1!"=="%char%" set string=!string:~0,-1!
( ENDLOCAL & REM RETURN VALUES
    IF "%~1" NEQ "" SET %~1=%string%
)
EXIT /b
```

If you're not used to using functions in batch files, [read this](http://www.dostips.com/DtTutoFunctions.php).

Comment: Thanks, but I need to call this from the command line. Any suggestions how ?

Comment: @HeinrichStack: Make a batch file that calls this function with its argument…

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice trick to remove trailing spaces based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32026314) of user [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560); I modified it so that all other spaces occurring in the string are preserved. So here is the code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem // This is the input string:
set "x=  This is   a text  string     containing  many   spaces.   "

rem // Ensure there is at least one trailing space; then initialise auxiliary variables:
set "y=%x% " & set "wd=" & set "sp="

rem // Now here is the algorithm:
set "y=%y: =" & (if defined wd (set "y=!y!!sp!!wd!" & set "sp= ") else (set "sp=!sp! ")) & set "wd=%"

rem // Return messages:
echo  input: "%x%"
echo output: "%y%"

endlocal
```

However, this approach fails when a character of the set `^`, `!`, `"` occurs in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Good tool for removing trailing spaces in files in windows:
http://mountwhite.net/en/spaces.html

Answer (score 0):

I just found a very nice solution for trimming off white-spaces of a string:
Have you ever called a sub-routine using `call` and expanded all arguments using `%*`? You will notice that any leading and/or trailing white-spaces are removed. Any white-spaces occurring in between other characters are preserved; so are all the other command token separators `,`, `;`, `=` and also the non-break space (character code `0xFF`). This effect I am going to utilise for my script:

```
@echo off

set "STR="
set /P STR="Enter string: "

rem /* Enable Delayed Expansion to avoid trouble with
rem    special characters: `&`, `<`, `>`, `|`, `^` */
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo You entered: `!STR!`
call :TRIM !STR!
echo And trimmed: `!RES!`
endlocal

exit /B

:TRIM
set "RES=%*"
exit /B
```

This script expects a string entered by the user which is then trimmed. This can of course also be applied on lines of a file (which the original question is about, but reading such line by line using `for /F` is shown in other answers anyway, so I skip this herein). To trim the string on one side only, add a single character to the opposite side prior to trimming and remove it afterwards.

This approach has got some limitations though: it does not handle characters `%`, `!`, `^` and `"` properly. To overcome this, several intermediate string manipulation operations become required:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "STR="
set /P STR="Enter string: "

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo You entered: `!STR!`
set "STR=!STR:%%=%%%%!"
set "STR=!STR:"=""!^"
if not "%STR%"=="%STR:!=%" set "STR=!STR:^=^^^^!"
set "STR=%STR:!=^^^!%"
call :TRIM !STR!
set "RES=!RES:""="!^"
echo And trimmed: `!RES!`
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B

:TRIM
set "RES=%*"
exit /B
```

---

#### Update

Both of the above scripts cannot handle the characters `&`, `<`, `>` and `|`, because `call` seems to become aborted as soon as such a character appears in an unquoted and unescaped manner.

However, I finally found a way to fix that and come up with an approach that can successfully deal with all characters (except perhaps some control characters, which I did not test):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem // The last white-space in `STRING` is a tabulator:
set "RESULT=" & set "STRING=   (<&>"^|)^^!^^^^;,=   ^"
echo Input string: `!STRING!`

rem // Double quotes to avoid troubles with unbalanced ones:
if defined STRING set "STRING=!STRING:"=""!^"
rem // Particularly handle carets and exclamation marks as delayed expansion is enabled:
if defined STRING set "STRING=!STRING:^=^^^^!"
if defined STRING set "STRING=%STRING:!=^^^!%" !
if defined STRING (
    rem // Escape all characters that `call` has got troubles with:
    set "STRING=!STRING:^=^^!"
    set "STRING=!STRING:&=^&!"
    set "STRING=!STRING:<=^<!"
    set "STRING=!STRING:>=^>!"
    set "STRING=!STRING:|=^|!"
)
rem /* Call the sub-routine here; the strigs `!=!` constitute undefined dummy variables
rem    with an illegal name, which eventually become removed; the purpose of them us to
rem    enable usage of that `call` inside of a `for` loop with the meta-variable `%%S`,
rem    which would otherwise become unintentionally expanded rather than `%%STRING%%`,
rem    which literally contained `%%S`; the `!=!` at the end is just there in case you
rem    want to append another string that could also match another `for` meta-variable;
rem    note that `!!` is not possible as this would be collapsed to a single `!`, so
rem    a (most probably undefined) variable `!STRING%!` would then become expanded: */
call :TRIM %%!=!STRING%%!=!
rem /* The caret doubling done by `call` does not need to be reverted, because due to
rem    doubling of the quotes carets appear unquoted, so implicit reversion occurs here;
rem    of course the doubling of the quotes must eventually be undone: */
if defined RESULT set "RESULT=!RESULT:""="!^"
echo Now trimmed: `!RESULT!`

endlocal
exit /B

:TRIM
    rem // This is the effective line that does the left- and right-trimming:
    set "RESULT=%*" !
    exit /B
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this Python 2 script to print lines with trailing whitespace and remove them manually:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys

if not sys.argv[1:]:
  sys.exit('usage: whitespace.py <filename>')

for no, line in enumerate(open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read().splitlines()):
  if line.endswith(' '):
    print no+1, line
```

I know that Python is not preinstalled for Windows, but at least it works cross-platform.