# Batch file that trims leading characters and lets me save where I want

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have (and will have) several text files that need the first 12 characters trimmed from the front of every line. Ideally, I'd like a batch file where I input the name and path of the file, the script runs, the file keeps its same name and location, or same location and you add a "_clean" on the end of the file name. Or, I drop the txt file on the batch file either one of the 2 things described above happens.

Is this possible?

Seems like you can get close with these examples:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/ITCG/thread/2a14d04c-c38b-4a89-95a2-e24aa586849c

[Remove trailing spaces from a file using Windows batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310711/dos-batch-remove-trailing-spaces-from-a-file)

**EDIT**

Someone helped me get to this point:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions 
set INFN=%~1 
set OUTFN=%INFN%_clean 
if exist "%OUTFN%" del "%OUTFN%" 
for /f "tokens=1*" %%c in ('type "%INFN%"') do ( 
>> "%OUTFN%" echo %%c %%d 
) 
endlocal
```

2 issues:

1) There's some text in those first 12 characters, so I need something that flat chops the first 12 characters out.

Every line begins with 2-3 characters, then 9-10 spaces like this:

```
99*10spaces*Text
```

or

```
100*9spaces*Text
```

I need just the text part

2) When the output file is saved, it's saved with the _clean appended to the .txt extension, even with file extensions hidden.

Comment: Show us your code and we can help you get it to work.

Comment: You don't seem to have made much effort to solve this yourself, which won't encourage people to help you.  However, as a suggestion, I'd say that a Powershell script could do this very simply - an in general the effort to learn Powershell over the DOS prompt will be time very well spent.

Comment: Currently importing the file into Excel 2007 using the fixed width option, then deleting the first column filled with empty space. I'm not very familiar with batch file coding, which is why I posted to this forum.

Comment: Someone helped me get to this point: 
'@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set INFN=%~1
set OUTFN=%INFN%_clean
if exist "%OUTFN%" del "%OUTFN%"
for /f "tokens=1*" %%c in ('type "%INFN%"') do (
  >> "%OUTFN%" echo %%c %%d
)
endlocal'

2 issues: 1) There's some text in those first 12 spaces, so I need something that flat chops the first 12 spaces out. 2) When the output file is saved, it's saved with the _clean appended to the .txt extension, even with file extensions hidden.

Comment: I edited your question to be more clear. I wonder if when you say "spaces" you mean "blanks" or mean "positions".

Comment: I apologize if I was unclear, every line begins with 2-3 characters, then 9-10 spaces like this: 99*10 spaces*Text or 100*9 spaces*Text. I need just the text part.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to chop the first 12 characters of every line of your input file, `cut` from **UnxUtils** http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ is your friend.

See `cut --help` and then try this simple one-line bat file

```
cut -c13- %1 >%~dpn1_CLEAN%~x1
```

Comment: This is a start, but I also need the other functionality, being able to drop a file in from anywhere and having the output file getting saved to the same spot as the original file.

Comment: and what have you tried and what problems you found?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to trim each line with native batch commands.

### UPDATE

Modified the code to build the output file name.

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

SET INFN=%1
SET OUTFN=%~n1_clean%~x1

IF EXIST "%OUTFN%" DEL "%OUTFN%"

FOR /F "tokens=* usebackq" %%c IN (%INFN%) DO (
  SET RESULT=%%c
  SET RESULT=!RESULT:~12!
  REM Displays the trimmed line in the console window
  ECHO !RESULT!
  REM Writes the trimmed line to the output file
  ECHO !RESULT!>>"%OUTFN%"
)

ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: Aphoria, when I try to drop a file on the code, it looks like the program runs but there's no "_clean" output file, either in the place the input file originated at or in the script location.

Comment: Try it now. I had to fix how `OUTFN` was built.

Comment: Still does not output a second file.

Comment: I bet you have spaces in your file names...I only tested without spaces. I fixed it to support spaces in the names...try it again.

Answer (score 1):

DragAndDrop.bat: It looks like a good solution would be a single .bat file (DragAndDrop.bat ) that uses check-and-balance (what-if) features from a single .vbs file (DragAndDropTrim12Add_clean.vbs).  Please see the syntax for the two files below.  Some extra scripting was used to keep script lines reasonably short.  This was updated to Rev 1.1 which adds a feature that gives the user the option to specify by key-in a new target directory.  The default has new files (copied or renamed) assume the path of the old files.  If you check-mark the Command Window Properties QuickEdit Mode CheckBox, you can easily paste in a new target directory.  Up-Arrow from the input prompt will also take you back to previous input.  With the exception of a popup message generated if you try to run DragAndDropTrim12Add_clean.vbs in non-cScript mode, all user focus can remain on the command lines.  If you choose to modify the DragAndDrop.bat file, use caution to avoid adding trailing white spaces on the set commands.  Continuing to use the setlocal call is also recommended to reduce impact on surrounding environment.

```
:DragAndDropDotBat
 @Title DragAndDrop.bat
  @rem Rev 1.1 11/10/2013 to add optional user specified target directory.
  @rem Labels are followed with "rem :LabelName" for easy GoTo troubleshooting. 
  @rem Script works best if CMD window buffer width set above file lengths.
  @echo off
  @echo ******* THIS IS FILE %0 %DATE% %TIME: =0% ********
  @echo User Choices are not case sensitive.
  @echo Leading or trailing white spaces are trimmed in derived names.
  @echo If Notepad OldFile is selected, the process will loop and run again.

   setlocal
    REM YOU MUST MANUALLY EDIT AND SET THE NEXT LINE PATH!!!!!
     Set FileToCall="x:\Scripts\DragAndDropTrim12Add_clean.vbs"
      Set BatNewFileTargetDir="UseOldFilePath"
       Set Per0=%0
        Set Per0=%Per0:"=%
         Set ProCount=0
          prompt :

:RunProcess
 rem :RunProcess
  Set /A ProCount=%ProCount% + 1

:SameAgain
 rem :SameAgain
  @echo off
   Set BatUserCho=S
    Set ProCntZeroFill=000%ProCount%
     Set strBatMode=
      Set strBatOFFP=
       Set strBatOFNm=
        Set strBatNFFP=
         Set strBatNFNm=
          Set strBatMsgLine0=
           Set BatNewFileTargetDir=%BatNewFileTargetDir%

 @echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
  @echo Process Cmd.%ProCntZeroFill:~-3% for file:  %1
   @echo Key-in e to exit, r to run, s to skip, n to notepad, t to new target dir :
    rem ECHO on
     For /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('cScript //NoLogo %FileToCall% %1') Do %%a
      If Not #%strBatMode%#==#BatCopyOldToNewThenEraseOld# GoTo PresentUserChoice
       Echo Old File = %strBatOFFP%
        dir "%strBatOFFP%"|findstr /i "%strBatOFNm%"
         Echo New File = %strBatNFFP%
          dir "%strBatNFFP%"|findstr /i "%strBatNFNm%"

:PresentUserChoice
 rem :PresentUserChoice
  @Set /P BatUserCho=%strBatMsgLine0% - Cmd.%ProCntZeroFill:~-3%:[%BatUserCho%]: 
   echo :%BatUserCho%:run-now|findstr /i ":R:" && GoTo RunNow
    echo :%BatUserCho%:exit-now|findstr /i ":E:" && GoTo DoExit
     echo :%BatUserCho%:skip-now|findstr /i ":S:" && GoTo ShiftNow
      echo :%BatUserCho%:notepad-now-and-rerun|findstr /i ":N:" && GoTo NotepadNow
       echo :%BatUserCho%:set-new-target-dir|findstr /i ":T:" && GoTo SetNewTarget
       %echo User Choice: %BatUserCho% not recognized, try again.
        GoTo SameAgain


:RunNow
 rem :RunNow
  If #%strBatMode%#==#BatCopyOldToNewThenEraseOld# GoTo BatCopyOldToNewThenEraseOld
   If #%strBatMode%#==#MsgThenExit# GoTo DoExit
    If #%strBatMode%#==#BatRenameOldToNew# GoTo BatRenameOldToNew
     If #%strBatMode%#==#MsgThenSkip# GoTo ShiftNow

:BatRenameOldToNew
 rem :BatRenameOldToNew
  dir "%strBatOFFP%"|findstr /i "%strBatOFNm%" 
   @echo on
    rename "%strBatOFFP%" "%strBatNFNm%"
     @echo off
      dir "%strBatNFFP%"|findstr /i "%strBatNFNm%"
       If Not Exist "%strBatNFFP%" GoTo BatRenameOldToNewAndNewNotFound
        GoTo ShiftNow

:BatRenameOldToNewAndNewNotFound
 rem :BatRenameOldToNewAndNewNotFound
  @echo New file not found: "%strBatNFFP%" 
   @echo ***** This is a rename failure. ******
    @echo off
     GoTo ShiftNow

:BatRenameOldToNewEnd
 rem :BatRenameOldToNewEnd

:BatCopyOldToNewThenEraseOld
 rem :BatCopyOldToNewThenEraseOld
  dir "%strBatOFFP%"|findstr /i "%strBatOFNm%" 
   dir "%strBatNFFP%"|findstr /i "%strBatNFNm%"
    @echo on
     Copy /-Y "%strBatOFFP%" "%strBatNFFP%"
      @echo off
       dir "%strBatOFFP%"|findstr /i "%strBatOFNm%" 
        dir "%strBatNFFP%"|findstr /i "%strBatNFNm%"
         If Not Exist "%strBatNFFP%"  GoTo BatCopyOldToNewAndNewNotFound
          @echo on
           Erase /P "%strBatOFFP%"
            dir "%strBatOFFP%"|findstr /i "%strBatOFNm%" 
             @echo off
              GoTo ShiftNow

:BatCopyOldToNewAndNewNotFound
 rem :BatCopyOldToNewAndNewNotFound
  @echo New file not found: "%strBatNFFP%" 
   @echo ***** The Delete process was skipped. ******

:BatCopyOldToNewThenEraseOldEnd
 ren :BatCopyOldToNewThenEraseOldEnd

:NotepadNow
 rem :NotepadNow
  rem Notepad FileName will hold bat file, Start Notepad will move on.
   echo on
    @rem Start Notepad "%strBatOFFP%"
     Notepad "%strBatOFFP%"
      @echo off
       GoTo SameAgain

:NotepadNowEnd
 rem :NotepadNowEnd

:SetNewTarget
 rem :SetNewTarget
  echo off
   echo ===============================================
    echo TargetDir=%BatNewFileTargetDir%
     echo Key-in your new targer directory on next line or s to skip:
      Set /P BatTrialTarget=-New Target : 
       echo ::%BatTrialTarget%:skip-now|findstr /i "::S:" && GoTo SameAgain
        Set BatTrialTarget=%BatTrialTarget:"=%
         Set BatTrialTarget=%BatTrialTarget:\\=\%
          Set BatTrialTarget=%BatTrialTarget%#:#
           Set BatTrialTarget=%BatTrialTarget: #:#=#:#%
            Set BatTrialTarget=%BatTrialTarget:\#:#=#:#%
             Set BatTrialTarget=%BatTrialTarget:#:#=%
              dir "%BatTrialTarget%"|findstr /i "Directory.of" && GoTo GoodTDir
               echo This directory not found: "%BatTrialTarget%"
                GoTo SetNewTarget

:GoodTDir
 rem :GoodTDir 
  Set BatNewFileTargetDir="%BatTrialTarget%"
   GoTo SameAgain

:SetNewTargetEnd
 rem :SetNewTargetEnd


:RunNowEnd
 rem RunNowEnd

:ShiftNow
 rem :ShiftNow
  shift
   If #:#%1#:#==#:##:# GoTo DoPause
    GoTo RunProcess

:DoExit
 rem :DoExit
  @echo off
   rem Comment out with rem the next four lines if not wanted.
    echo Call "%Per0%" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9>"%TEMP%\ResumeNext9.bat"
     echo Call "%Per0%" %*>"%TEMP%\ResumeAll.bat"
      echo To Resume: Call "%TEMP%\ResumeNext9.bat"
       echo Or Resume: Call "%TEMP%\ResumeAll.bat"
        endlocal
         ping -n 3 localhost>nul
          GoTo DragAndDropDotBatEnd

:DoPause
 rem :DoPause
  @echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
   echo File %Per0% 
    echo has completed input values [%ProCntZeroFill:~-3%]
     @echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
      endlocal
       Pause

:DragAndDropDotBatEnd



'''DragAndDropTrim12Add_clean.vbs
'''Rev 1.1 11/10/2013 to add optional user specified target directory.
'''Problem Statement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760911/
'''batch-file-that-trims-leading-characters-and-lets-me-save-where-i-want
'''I have (and will have) several text files that need the first 12 characters 
'''trimmed from the front of every line. Ideally, I'd like a batch file where 
'''I input the name and path of the file, the script runs, the file keeps its 
'''same name and location, or same location and you add a "_clean" on the end 
'''of the file name. Or, I drop the txt file on the batch file either one of 
'''the 2 things described above happens.
'''Is this possible?

'''Assuming the existing Directory and File structures look like this:
'''x:\aaa\bbb\c c\2013_11_05_aMyTextFile 05.txt
'''x:\aaa\bbb\c c\2013_11_05_aMyTextFile001.txt
'''x:\aaa\bbb\c c\2013_11_05_aMyTextFile002.txt
'''x:\aaa\bbb\c c\2013_11_05_aMyTextFile003.txt
'''x:\aaa\bbb\c c\2013_11_05_aMyTextFile004.txt
'''x:\aaa\bbb\c c\2013_11_05_bMyTextFile002.txt

'''And you want then to look like this:
'''x:\aaa\bbb\c c\MyTextFile 05_clean.txt
'''x:\aaa\bbb\c c\MyTextFile001_clean.txt
'''x:\aaa\bbb\c c\MyTextFile002_clean.txt
'''x:\aaa\bbb\c c\MyTextFile003_clean.txt
'''x:\aaa\bbb\c c\MyTextFile004_clean.txt

'''And supporting scripts are:
'''x:\Scripts\DragAndDrop.bat
'''x:\Scripts\DragAndDropTrim12Add_clean.vbs

'''To use from File Explorer:
'From File Explorer, highlight the existing files, then right click and choose "Copy" –
'''then drop (paste) them onto x:\Scripts\DragAndDrop.bat
'''This will walk you through the renaming processes.

'DragAndDrop.bat  will call DragAndDropTrim12Add_clean.vbs and invoke the following 
'''     Check processes:
'''1    DragAndDropTrim12Add_clean.vbs is called in CScript mode.
'''2    Script command line values are being passed from bat file to vbs file
'''3    Modified values are passed back to bat file and set by the For loop.
'''4    New trimmed and appended file name does not conflict with an existing file.
'''5    Files passed on the drop-generated command line still exist.
'''6    File to be processed does not already contain the "_clean" string
'''7    File to be processed can support having 12 characters trimmed.
'''8    As each file is processed, the script gives several "User Choice" options. 


'''Bat File Values to pass
'''Set strBatMode=MsgThenExit,MsgThenSkip,BatCopyOldToNewThenEraseOld,BatRenameOldToNew
'''Set strBatOFFP=strOldFileFullPath
'''Set strBatOFNm=strOldFileName
'''Set strBatNFFP=strNewFileFullPath
'''Set strBatNFNm=strNewFileName
'''Set strBatMsgLine0=Note:Do not use double quote.


   Option Explicit ''Requires that you dimension all variables
   Dim funInStrVal, funLastHitVal, StdOut, StdErr, objFSO, strWScriptArg0 
   Dim intLastHit, intLenMinus, intTrimLeadNum, strTrailString
   Dim objDialog, intReturn, strMsg1, strNewFileFullPath, strNFN, strTrS
   Dim strOldFileFullPath, strOldFilePath, strOldFileName, strOldFileNameNoExt
   Dim strNewFileName, strS, wshShell, strBatNewFileTargetDir

   If InStr(1,LCase(WScript.FullName),"cscript.exe",1) = 0 Then
      Dim objShell, Rsp01
      Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
      Rsp01 = objShell.Popup("This script must be run using cScript" _
      & vbCrLf & "Error from " & Wscript.ScriptFullName & vbCrLf _
      & "Use: cScript //NoLogo """ & Wscript.ScriptFullName _
      & """",10,"     Error Because Not Using cScript " _
      & "(10 sec timeout)",vbOKOnly + vbCritical)
      Set objShell = Nothing
      Wscript.Quit
   End If


   intTrimLeadNum = 12
   strTrailString = "_clean"
   ''Set StdIn = WScript.StdIn
   Set StdOut = WScript.StdOut
   Set StdErr = WScript.StdErr
   Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

   strBatNewFileTargetDir = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%BatNewFileTargetDir%" )
   Set wshShell = Nothing
   strBatNewFileTargetDir = Replace(strBatNewFileTargetDir,"""","") ''remove dq



   If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
      strWScriptArg0=Trim(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
   Else
      strMsg1="NO Command Line" _
      & " value passed to: " & Wscript.ScriptFullName
      StdErr.WriteLine "WARNING: " & strMsg1 
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set BatUserCho=E"
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatMode=MsgThenExit"
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatMsgLine0=.........................Press Enter to Exit"
      Wscript.Quit
   End If

   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

   If objFSO.FileExists(strWScriptArg0) = False Then
      strMsg1 = strWScriptArg0 & " is not a valid file name."
      StdErr.WriteLine "WARNING: " & strMsg1 
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set BatUserCho=S"
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatMode=MsgThenSkip"
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatMsgLine0=.........................Press Enter to Skip"
      Set objFSO = Nothing
      Wscript.Quit
   End If


      strOldFileFullPath = strWScriptArg0
      strOldFilePath = FunLeftOrRtStr(strOldFileFullPath, "\", "L")
      strS = strOldFileFullPath  ''Short String for using less columns
      strOldFileName = Right(strS,Len(strS) - (FunLastHitInt(strS, "\") + 1))
      strOldFileNameNoExt = Trim(FunLeftOrRtStr(strOldFileName, ".", "L"))
      strNFN=strOldFileNameNoExt
      strTrS=strTrailString &  "." & FunLeftOrRtStr(strOldFileName, ".", "R")




   If Len(strOldFileNameNoExt) <= intTrimLeadNum Then 
      strMsg1 = strOldFileFullPath & " Base File Name is:" & vbCrLf & Len(strOldFileNameNoExt) _
      & " characters which is too short for the " & intTrimLeadNum & " char trim."
      StdErr.WriteLine "WARNING: " & strMsg1 
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set BatUserCho=S"
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatMode=MsgThenSkip"
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatMsgLine0=.........................Press Enter to Skip"
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatOFFP=" & strOldFileFullPath
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatOFNm=" & strOldFileName
      Set objFSO = Nothing
      Wscript.Quit
   End If

      ''Remove any leading or trailing white space with Trim()
      strNewFileName = Trim(Right(strNFN, Len(strNFN) - intTrimLeadNum)) & strTrS

 StdErr.WriteLine "strBatNewFileTargetDir=" & strBatNewFileTargetDir

   If strBatNewFileTargetDir = "UseOldFilePath" Or InStr(1,strBatNewFileTargetDir, "\") = 0 Then
      strNewFileFullPath = strOldFilePath & "\" & strNewFileName
   Else
      strNewFileFullPath = strBatNewFileTargetDir & "\" & strNewFileName
   End If

   If objFSO.FileExists(strNewFileFullPath) = True Then
      StdErr.WriteLine "WARNING: " & strNewFileName & " existing."
      StdOut.WriteLine "Echo You can Copy Old and overwrite Existing"
      StdOut.WriteLine "Echo You will be prompted for the Overwrite:"
      StdOut.WriteLine "Echo You will also be prompted for the Delete:"
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatMode=BatCopyOldToNewThenEraseOld"
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set BatUserCho=R"
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatMsgLine0=..Press Enter to Copy Old to New Then Delete Old"
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatOFFP=" & strOldFileFullPath
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatOFNm=" & strOldFileName
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatNFFP=" & strNewFileFullPath
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatNFNm=" & strNewFileName
      Set objFSO = Nothing
      Wscript.Quit
   Else
      StdOut.WriteLine "Echo Old File = " & strOldFileFullPath
      If InStr(1,strOldFileName, strTrailString) > 0 Then
         strMsg1 = strOldFileName & " already contains: " & strTrailString
         StdErr.WriteLine "***WARNING: " & strMsg1 & "***"
         StdOut.WriteLine "Echo New File Would = " & strNewFileFullPath
         StdOut.WriteLine "Set BatUserCho=S"
         StdOut.WriteLine "Echo...........Key-in r to RUN and Rename Old to New. "
         StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatMsgLine0=................... or Press Enter to Skip" 
      Else
         StdOut.WriteLine "Echo New File = " & strNewFileFullPath
         StdOut.WriteLine "Set BatUserCho=R"
         StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatMsgLine0=...........Rename Old to New---Press " _
         & "Enter to RUN"
      End If
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatMode=BatRenameOldToNew"
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatOFFP=" & strOldFileFullPath
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatOFNm=" & strOldFileName
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatNFFP=" & strNewFileFullPath
      StdOut.WriteLine "Set strBatNFNm=" & strNewFileName
   End If



   If 1 = 2 Then  ''''Change to 1 = 1 for testing.  StdErr will not go to bat file
      Dim strInVal, strTFileName, strTNewFile, strTFileNameNoExt, strTFileExt
      ''strInVal = "X:\aaa\bbb\c c\12345.678"
      strInVal = strWScriptArg0
      intLastHit = FunLastHitInt(strInVal, ".")
      StdErr.WriteLine " :  strInVal=" & strInVal
      StdErr.WriteLine " : Path+File=" & Left(strInVal,intLastHit)
      StdErr.WriteLine " : Ext=" & Right(strInVal,Len(strInVal) - intLastHit)
      StdErr.WriteLine " : Path=" & FunLeftOrRtStr(strInVal, "\", "L")
      StdErr.WriteLine " :      FileName=" & FunLeftOrRtStr(strInVal, "\", "R")
      strTFileName=Right(strInVal,Len(strInVal) - (FunLastHitInt(strInVal, "\") + 1))
      strTFileNameNoExt = FunLeftOrRtStr(strTFileName, ".", "L")
      strTFileExt="." & FunLeftOrRtStr(strInVal, ".", "R")
      StdErr.WriteLine " : FileNameNoExt=" &  strTFileNameNoExt
      StdErr.WriteLine " :           Ext=" & strTFileExt
      strTNewFile=Right(strTFileNameNoExt, Len(strTFileNameNoExt) - intTrimLeadNum)
      StdErr.WriteLine " :       NewFile=" & strTNewFile & strTrailString & strTFileExt

   End If ''If 1 = 2 Then



   Function FunLastHitInt(funInputString, funHitChar)
    '''Dim funInStrVal, funLastHitVal (Required at top of script)
    '''For Dir Use: Left(strFullPath,FunLastHitInt(strFullPath, "\"))
    ''For File Use: 
    ''Right(strFullPath,Len(strFullPath) - (FunLastHitInt(strFullPath, "\") + 1))
    If InStr(1,funInputString, funHitChar) > 0 Then
       funInStrVal = 2
       Do Until funInStrVal = 1 ''funLastHitVal will eventually = 0 + 1
          funLastHitVal = InStr(funInStrVal, funInputString, funHitChar)
          If funLastHitVal > 0 Then
             FunLastHitInt = funLastHitVal - 1
          End If
          funInStrVal = funLastHitVal + 1
          ''Wscript.Echo "funLastHitVal=" & funLastHitVal
       Loop
    Else
       FunLastHitInt = 0
    End If
   End Function ''Function FunLastHitInt(funInputString, funLastChar)


   Function FunLeftOrRtStr(funFullPathLR, funHitCharLR, funLorR)
    If InStr(1,funFullPathLR,funHitCharLR) = 0 Then
       FunLeftOrRtStr = funFullPathLR
    ElseIf UCase(funLorR) = "R" Then
       intLenMinus = (FunLastHitInt(funFullPathLR, funHitCharLR) + Len(funHitCharLR))
       FunLeftOrRtStr = Right(funFullPathLR,Len(funFullPathLR) - intLenMinus)
    Else
       FunLeftOrRtStr = Left(funFullPathLR,FunLastHitInt(funFullPathLR, funHitCharLR))
    End If
   End Function


  Set objFSO = Nothing
  Wscript.Quit

'''DragAndDropTrim12Add_clean.vbsEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this question out to another website, the following is what we finally got working exactly how I wanted:

```
@echo off
if not exist "%~1" (echo Error & pause & exit /b 1) 
echo do until wsh.stdin.atendofstream:wsh.echo mid(wsh.stdin.readline, 9):loop> %temp%\_t.vbs
more /T8 < "%~1" | cscript //nologo %temp%\_t.vbs > "%~dpn1_clean%~x1"
del %temp%\_t.vbs
del %1
```

Thanks again for everyone's help.

Comment: This works in the sense I don't get any errors running it. However, it does not do what you asked in your question.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, it looks like most of the leading space was a tab. Someone helped me create a program that converted that tab space into regular spaces, then I had to tweak it. Now it cuts of the correct amount of leading "positions" I need it to cut, creates a new file, and deletes the old one.