# Combing muliple CCS files into one overall css file

Tags: css, batch-file

Hello is it possible to have a .bat file to run and then combine multiple css files and make them into one for faster loading time instead of loading each individual stylesheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
copy test1.css+test2.css test3.css
```

Comment: This works but if I wanted to remove all the spaces to is that possible?

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310711/dos-batch-remove-trailing-spaces-from-a-file) can probably lead you to tools to accomplish this. It would be very slow. I suggest you consider using php to both combine the css files and make changes to its contents. It would be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line in a .bat file:

```
type file1.css file2.css > combined.css
```

Keep in mind, unless you are using a specially configured Windows server, you will need to run this locally.