# Batch Remove Trailing Whitespace in a Text File

Tags: batch-file

[Remove trailing spaces from a file using Windows batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310711/dos-batch-remove-trailing-spaces-from-a-file) and [How to remove trailing and leading whitespace for user-provided input in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001999/how-to-remove-trailing-and-leading-whitespace-for-user-provided-input-in-a-batch) seem to be similar questions, but I can't get any of the answers to work.

I have a text file, say C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\sometext.txt that has a long list of numbers, some with trailing whitespace. How can I loop through and remove the whitespace at the end of each line?  I'd like to do this all in batch. It'll be in a file with some other batch commands in it.

Comment: does it have to be a batch file ? Do you deploy your "solution" to a lot of machines and want the least of dependencies ? If not try to get something more "modern". I assume you are on any Windows >= XP. Use powershell for that or windows scripting host, they can be called from your already existing batch.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what in the other answers didn't work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regrettably, you don't show us an example from your file, so we're left to assume from your desription.

Assuming your file is something like

```
1
22
3
64
```

where some of the lines have trailing spaces, then

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
FOR /f "usebackq" %%a IN (q30594509.txt) DO (
 SET /a num=%%a
 ECHO(!num!
)
)>u:\newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q30594509.txt` containing the above data for my testing.

Produces u:\newfile.txt

Comment: After I removed the "u:\" as I don't have a "u" drive, this code gave me a "missing operator" error.

Comment: @tyebillion : If you simply removed the 'u:\' then this should have created the `newfile.txt` file in your current directory. You should be able to replace `u:\` with any other path to select a different drive/path (but must be `"quoted"` if the destination contains spaces). The error reported indicates a problem with reproducing the code. Best to copy-and-paste, preferably using a decent editor like editplus. Batch is remarkably sensitive to syntax. Removing the `>u:\newfile.txt` completely should report to the screen. That would be my first port of call.