# How to trim leading and trailing white-spaces by a single command?

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd

Supposing you have a string value in a variable `STRING`, how can you remove leading and trailing whitespaces with a single command (line)?

For instance, the string is (the `_` stands for tab here; double-quotes just for illustration, not part of string value):

```
"  two spaces, trimmed text string, space-tab-space _ "
```

The expected output is (double-quotes again not part of string):

```
"two spaces, trimmed text string, space-tab-space"
```

How to accomplish that?

In this context, I'm talking about spaces and (horizontal) tabulators when I say "whitespaces".

Comment: It's not possible with a single batch command, but see [How to remove trailing and leading whitespace for user-provided input in a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3001999)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to trim both spaces *and* tabs in a single line, but just for spaces you may use [this trick](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429&p=41356#p41356):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "x=  two spaces, trimmed text string, space-space-space   "
echo "%x%"

rem The single line:
set "word=%x: =" & (if "!word!" neq "" set "x2=!x2! !word!") & set "word=%" & set "x2=!x2:~1!"

echo "%x2%"
```

Comment: Interesting. Works even with `set "x=   spaces, ..., space(s)-tab   "` (note  a trailing `<tab>` after spaces).  However, I'm afraid it will fail for `set "x=   spaces, ..., no-trailing-space"`

Comment: @JosefZ: Yes. The [original code](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429&p=41356#p41356) have an additional `set "x=%x% "` line to avoid this problem, but I cheat a little in order to make this method fit "in one line". **`;-)`**

Comment: Excellent effort, @Aacini, thank you! It would be cool if you mention the required trailing space in your answer somehow (perhaps a `rem`). Furthermore, I found out that some characters cause trouble: `%` signs (must be doubled prior to processing), `!` marks (they simply disappear; also `^!` and `^^!` sequences), and double-quotes `"`; it would be great too if you mentioned these restrictions in your answer.

Comment: I just found out that two or more consecutive spaces are changed to a single one by this command line...

Comment: I just found a very nice way to trim strings: take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38598214)...

Comment: @aschipfl: Two posts after the one that contains [the original code](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429&p=41356#p41356) (this is the third time I included such link here) I posted a modification of this method with this explanation: _"I realized that my previous method to trim leading and trailing spaces also reduce several spaces between words to just one. The new method below correctly preserve multiple spaces between words"_.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning *leading* whitespaces only, the following code works (_ means <kbd>TAB</kbd>):

```
set "STRING=  two spaces, trimmed text string, space-tab-space _ "

rem no "delims=" option given, so defaulting to spaces and tabs:
for /F "tokens=* eol= " %%S in ("%STRING%") do set "LEFTTRIMMED=%%S"

echo "%LEFTTRIMMED%"
```

However, the trailing whitespaces are still present; but they can removed by the approaches shown in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9310711).