# Ignore processing lines which start with # in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a property file with name 'props.txt' which has values like -

```
test=props
#test2=props
```

I have written a batch script to put these properties in Windows 10 environment variables as following:

```
#@ECHO OFF
For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (props.txt) DO (

    IF NOT "%A:~0,1%"=="#" (
        SETX "%%A"  "%%B"
    )
)
```

Now all the properties are put into environment variables, even if they start with '#'. I want to ignore the properties which start with '#'. How can I do that?
Also, I want to skip blank lines. Is there any change which I would need to do?

Comment: You cannot do string manipulation on a `FOR` token variable.  You have to assign it to an environmental variable first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `EOL=#` it skips all lines beginning with `#`, the default is `EOL=;`.
Blank lines are always skipped by `FOR /F`, it's a problem to fetch them, if you want to.

```
For /F "tokens=1* EOL=# delims==" %%A IN (props.txt) DO (
    ...
```

Comment: Can you also tell me if there is any simple way to trim keys and values before putting them to environment variables?

Comment: @N.. Take a look at [Remove trailing spaces from a file using Windows batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9318485/463115) That also works for variables